# Вёрстка на iOS (Safari) открывается уменьшённой

Tags: responsive, вёрстка, ios, safari

Доброго времени суток.

Верстаю на Bootstrap адаптивный дизайн, проблема в том, что Safari на айфоне открывает сайт с обычной шириной, как на десктопе, только уменьшенный - от чего вся адаптивность улетучивается. Пробую вручную уменьшать ширину контейнера при обнаружение айфона через JS, адаптивность появляется - но сайт по прежнему остается уменьшенным, и с возможностью увеличить

Как пофиксить, собственно, и в чём баг? Может кто-то сталкивался с похожим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла строчка в head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```